Show case view Error - Flutter Mobile App
The showcase view working in debug mode. But in release mode showcase view not displaying.
This ShowCaseWidget widget cannot be marked as needing to build because the framework is already in the process of building widgets. A widget can be marked as needing to be built during the build phase only if one of its ancestors is currently building. This exception is allowed because the framework builds parent widgets before children, which means a dirty descendant will always be built. Otherwise, the framework might not visit this widget during this build phase.
This is the error i have seen while the showcase triggers.
  WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback(
      (_) {
           if (mounted) {
                    _startShowcase(); // Start the showcase if the widget is still mounted
             }
        });

  Future<void> _startShowcase() async {
    ShowCaseWidget.of(context).startShowCase([showcaseKey]);
    _dismissShowcase(); // Dismiss the showcase
  }

I have tried like this also but still in release mode not displaying the show case.
Consider this Package : showcaseview: ^3.0.0

What does your  _dismissShowcase() do? And why you are dismissing the showcase right after you play it? If you comment out this method call, do you see the showcase in release mode?

I've resolved the issue. I was using a VisibilityDetector in the bottom navigation bar, which caused the widget to reload before it fully loaded. This was why it wasn't working correctly in release mode.
